# Confirm Before Removal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a confirmation option before a to-do list item is removed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$('.sortlist').on('click','.delete',function() {
  $(this).parent('li').effect('puff', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Confirm box and add your deletion logic on true.

```
$('.sortlist').on('click','.delete',function() {
    var r = confirm("Are you want to delete!");
    if (r == true) {
        // Delete record
        $(this).parent('li').effect('puff', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        });
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

And for more you can refer this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: Using the confirm box method helped solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Urbandev, If this helped solve the problem please accept Bhupendra's answer as the Top Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UrbanDev, Just to confirm im with you on this one before i post any code.. Are you looking for a popup confirmation box as such to alert the user that he/she is about to remove an item from their to-do list.  (if the user clicks no then the function is canceled and if the user clicks yes then the function is carried on)  Does this sound about right?

Unfortunately im unable to comment to your question just yet as im not quite at the right level of REP however so i have to provide an answer to find out more information And for that i will update my response to an actual answer as soon as possible once you provide a little more information to your question.

From the tags attached im guessing you don't mind if its in java-script or jquery right just as long as it gets the job done?

Will provide an update to you as soon as you let me know a little bit more info, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I'm looking for a pop up confirmation box to alert the user before they remove an item from the to-do list. I'm still learning both, so any java-script of jquery will help.